# In sharepoint 2013 should i use web templates or apps?

Tags: web-template, app

I have been asked to create sharepoint site to track company expenses.  Functionality included:

-Implement for SP 2013
-Users create expense requests.
-Managers approve requests.
-Basic reporting.
-Emails sent to managers at the end of every day updating them of new requests.

In sharepoint 2010 i would create a wsp file (then import to vs2010) and implement using a web template, is this what i should do in SP 2013 or should i use the app model?

Comment: I feel a web template would be all that is required here, unless you need to do any custom apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to distribute your solution, use apps. Otherwise, in your case web template is more usable for end users and simplier in development.